# OpenLayers externalGraphic, georeferencing of images

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I need to georeference a non georeferenced image using Openlayers. I found a great [example](http://gis.ibbeck.de/ginfo/apps/OLExamples/OL27/examples/ExternalGraphicOverlay/ExternalGraphicOverlay.asp) that shows how can I do it, but there is something that I can't understand:

How do I calculate the "theResolution" variable in the source code (line 130)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolution in OpenLayers will refer to the units of distance divided by the number of pixels. Distance units will of course depend on your projection, in this example, spherical mercator, which is meters. So to calculate that value for your external images, you just need to divide the width or height in meters of the image by its width or height in pixels.

If you look, here: http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/browser/trunk/openlayers/lib/OpenLayers/Layer.js you will see how some of the resolution calculations are done in OpenLayers.